# Making sense of the results of machine learning feature selection

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection

**Credits:**

I recently used vowpal wabbit ( https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/wiki ) and Ariel F's weight loss github ( https://github.com/arielf/weight-loss ) along with Atulya's data scrapper ( https://github.com/atulya2109/Stats-Royale-Python ) to run machine learning on 54,000+ games of Clash Royale (a card dueling game like Magic the Gathering).

**Results**

Red (negative) means stronger card characters in Clash Royale because they beat the opponent and made his score go down.
https://codepen.io/TylerL-uxai/full/ayVEbm/

**Where I'm Confused**

I don't understand why a card like tornado4 (seen in 1896 games) can rank most powerful, when tornado5 (seen in 3400 games) is considered slightly weak. Just using tornado levels 4, 5, and 6 as examples, shouldn't they all be closer together? Why would level 5 tornado correlate more with losing than winning, when the weaker tornado level 4 is considered the most powerful card?

Did I do something wrong collecting data? I've been working 2 weeks on this and feel like the data is finally reliable... but apparently it's not?

**Data Mining Rules**

- Games by pretty expert players with a rating of at least 3000 (the players on average were about 3500 to 4500)
- Assigned "weight" to the players rather than using trophy ranking. I found that one game that dropped 500 trophies would throw off the data, so each game is equal with a +/- 25 point win/lose
- No draws or 2v2 games
- Tried to make sure there were no duplicates
- Only games within the last 48 hours

Comment: You should summarize a bit of the rules of the game, otherwise people who doesn't know about the cards will not be take the time to learn the domain to help

Comment: Thanks @Picarus. I edited the question with your suggestion.